# Pop-up boxes in MS Word are too small

Tags: microsoft-word, user-interface

MS Word version 1908, build 11929.20648 on Windows 10.  My problem is that some of the time, a pop-up box that Word shows me is too small, making the options being presented unreadable or inaccessible.

For example, a "do you want to save changes before closing?" pop-up box where the button labels are outside the viewable area of the box:

[image]

Another example:  a list of items where the text is compressed or visually overwritten so that information is lost.  I don't have an really bad example of this one handy, but imagine if the the list were longer and therefore more compressed:

[image]

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

P.S.  My memory is hazy on whether the same problem has occurred in other MS Office applications on the same computer, in case you were wondering.

Comment: Are you using a display with DPI scaling? You can check this by right-clicking on your desktop and selecting "Display settings": if the slider is at anything other than 100%, you're using DPI scaling.

Comment: Also in Settings, search for Text Size and set Text Size for 110% or higher. This works with and separately from display scaling.

Answer (score 0):

The initial comments from @squircle and @John provided useful breadcrumbs to follow, but setting DPI scaling back to 100% set the screen to such a shrunken layout that it was unusable, and various combinations of changing Text Size or changing the monitor resolution didn't quite overcome that.

Plus, this happens on my laptop screen as well as on the external monitors I was using at the office back before COVID shelter-in-place.  That made me still be interested a solution that was particular to Word.

But following those threads, I landed on the advice "Another per application solution is to right click the offending .exe and on the Compatibility tab choose the "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" option" at https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f7xfk/psa_solution_to_blurry_text_on_125_dpi_in_windows/cts4lvx/.

Experimenting with that advice a bit, I think that when I *de-select* the "High DPI scaling override" checkbox in WINWORD.EXE -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Change high DPI settings, that makes everything quite OK, as far as I can tell at this point.